# Команда для подключения к ftp/sftp через Nautilus

Tags: ubuntu

Подскажите пожалуйста, как через терминал подключаться по ftp/sftp через Nautilus ?
Чтобы не нужно было после выполнения команды вводить пароль.

Я пробовал делать так:

```
sudo nautilus sftp://root@123.123.123.123/
```

после запуска этой команды всплывает окошко куда надо вводить пароль от подключения. Как мне сделать, чтобы пароль тоже вводился автоматически?

Comment: в стопицотмильённый раз: используйте аккаунт root (в данном случае — посредством программы sudo) **только** для администрирования системы. вы ведь **уже** бардак с принадлежностью файлов/каталогов в своём домашнем каталоге развели. зачем? где вы про это услышали/прочитали — что надо где ни попадя для всего подряд повышать привилегии?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а как это связано с моим вопросом ?

Comment: наверно, никак. ведь слово «sudo» попало в текст вашего вопроса чисто случайно.